# Seperate folder for django models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am working on Django project that will utilize different apps to fulfill certain task. Since these apps will be referring to much same data to complete these task I figure it makes since to create a separate folder with the models like this:

```
--Project
 --App1
 --App2
 --models
  ---model1.py
  ---model2.py
```

Right now I'm having trouble with Django recognizing the models as existing, every time I run a makemigrations Django does not detect that any changes have been made
I attempted to put a `__init__.py` file in the /models folder but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: The `models` folder has to be under an app. I don't think you can declare models directly at the project level. [This docs section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package) should help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not seperate models in django projects dude! models.py file must be in app folder, That's why you can not migrate.

Comment: But the apps I'm working refer to the same data for certain purposes. Having the same models.py in every app just seems clunky

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No it's not clunky. You can make a python file in your root directory for common data and in models.py file in each app refer to this file.

Comment: Ok so have a file with common data in my root directory and use the import function in each models.py?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: yes, you can separate models. check this mate, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package